# Which command would replace IDENTITY INSERT ON/OFF from SQLServer in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, t-sql, migration, sequence, identity-insert

I have to migrate this query (simplified here) from T-SQL to ORACLE

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON

INSERT INTO table (id, value) VALUES (1, 2)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT table OFF
```

`id` being an Identity field in SQLServer.

I have the same table with a sequence in ORACLE, I couldn't find a snippet that shows how to disable the sequence and set it to start again with the MAX(id) + 1.

Any ORACLE expert can help me with this?

Thanks,
Rodrigo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to disable the identity in Oracle.  Since you are using sequences, just don't use it for that insert.

That is, instead of

```
insert into table (id, values) values (table_seq.nextval, 2)
```

you use

```
insert into table (id, values) values (1, 2)
```

As to your second question about restarting the sequence, I think that is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle) in SO.

Comment: If you intend to keep the identity the same (which appears to be the case) this isn't a solution.

Comment: @Nate: You missed where it says "MAX(id) +1"

Answer (score 1):

Messing with columns populated by Oracle sequences in this way seems like a Bad Idea. In Oracle, you are typically maintaining a column populated via sequences with a trigger. If you start turning this feature on and off, and resetting the sequence ad lib, you run the risk of a sequence not being available when another process needs it, or getting reset to a value that has been used already but not committed.

Comment: Triggers are unnecessary as long as `sequence.NEXTVAL` is used in all INSERT statements for the table, which should really only happen in a single stored procedure anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the sequences and re-create them when you're done with the max+1 value.

Comment: assuming this is a 1-time ETL

Comment: This invalidates code that depends on that sequence and it drops all privileges in the process as well. If that's not a problem then this is the easiest option.