# Problem with sequence in oracle

Tags: perl, oracle, programming-languages, ora-01722

Firstly i have created a sequence in oracle in perl script.I get a error statiing sequence already created error.Is there any means to reset the sequence(Create or replace doesnt work)

```
create or replace sequence test_seq start with 1900 increment by 1 nomaxvalue

sprintf("INSERT INTO Custodian_New (Loginid,Type, Id, User, TimeCreated, RcNumber) values ('%s',1, %d, '%s', %d, '%s')", seq_name.nextVal,$dd, $Name, time(), $rc_num);
```

The above statement in perl script prints:'test_seqnextVal' for the sequence.
So an error

```
DBD::Oracle::db do failed: ORA-01722: invalid number (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*>seq_name )occurs.
```

Please suggest me on what is the problem?Thanks.

Comment: I think you will have to drop and create the sequence again , replace won't work

Comment: why do you want to reset the sequence?

Comment: Is `seq_name.nextval` supposed to be in double-quotes too? You don't want the single quotes around the `%s`, it's going to try to insert the string "seq_name.nextVal" instead of the number that would generate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the ORA-01722, your `sprintf` is has single quotes around the `%s`, so it will try to insert the string `"seq_name.nextVal"` into the number field instead of a value from the sequence; that string can't be converted to a number, hence the error. You can remove the single quotes:

```
sprintf("INSERT INTO Custodian_New (Loginid, Type, Id, User, TimeCreated, RcNumber) values (%s, 1, %d, '%s', %d, '%s')", "seq_name.nextVal", $dd, $Name, time(), $rc_num);
```

Or just embed the sequence directly as there doesn't seem to be any point building it dynamically:

```
sprintf("INSERT INTO Custodian_New (Loginid, Type, Id, User, TimeCreated, RcNumber) values (seq_name.nextVal, 1, %d, '%s', %d, '%s')", $dd, $Name, time(), $rc_num);
```

Or even better, use bind variables and set those to `$dd` etc. I'd also use `sysdate` instead of passing in `time()`, but don't know if that really makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

For the sequence reset, please see [*How do I reset a sequence in Oracle?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle)