# How to change Sequence LAST_NUMBER in Oracle

Tags: oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset a sequence in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle)

I would like to change one parameter of sequence LAST_NUMBER to some number, how can i do it through SQL query.

ALTER SEQUENCE MSG_MESSAGE_SEQUENCE RESTART WITH 97

And it is not working.

Comment: If you want to increase the value, use a big increment (diff between desired and actual) for one nextval-call and then reset increment to real value: `ALTER SEQUENCE mySeq INCREMENT BY 1000004; SELECT mySeq.nextval from dual; ALTER SEQUENCE mySeq INCREMENT BY 1;` source: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2512696 
For decreasing you can drop and recreate your sequence, it that is an option for you.

Comment: The correct syntax is:
ALTER SEQUENCE MSG_MESSAGE_SEQUENCE RESTART **START** WITH 97;

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle):

```
'select MSG_MESSAGE_SEQUENCE.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;

execute immediate
'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name || ' increment by 97 - ' || l_val || ' minvalue 97';
```