# Using sequences as primary key

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have one table called `INTER` and I want to transfer some data from `INTER` to `FINAL` (a new table which is already created and empty) using a procedure.

I have to make use of sequence as a primary key for the `FINAL` table. `INTER` is the parent table and it has all columns present in `FINAL`.

I have created a sequence `M_SQ`. Here is what I tried:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE STAGING_TO_CUSTOMER
    AS
     BEGIN
         INSERT INTO FINAL (C_ID,C_NAME,C_PHONE,C_ADDRESS)
         SELECT M_SQ.NEXTVAL,C_NAME,C_PHONE,C_ADDRESS FROM INTER;
         COMMIT;
         EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
         ROLLBACK;
     END;
```

This procedure gets compiled but no records are transferred to `FINAL`.

Can somebody help?  I am using sqldeveloper 11g.

Comment: get rid of the "EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS". that is just serving to mask any errors. Once removed then rerun the procedure. you may then see an error raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you actually have to run the procedure for it to do what is inside it:

```
BEGIN
    STAGING_TO_CUSTOMER;
END;
```

Also, your procedure might as well look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE STAGING_TO_CUSTOMER AS
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO FINAL (C_ID,C_NAME,C_PHONE,C_ADDRESS)
     SELECT M_SQ.NEXTVAL,C_NAME,C_PHONE,C_ADDRESS FROM INTER;
     COMMIT;
     EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
         ROLLBACK;
         RAISE;
END;
```

So you know if something happens.

Comment: I know..I tried running the procedure. As I told, the procedure gets compiled and runs successfully but; when I check the FINAL table, it is still empty

Comment: I got the following error:- Error report:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.STAGING_TO_CUSTOMER", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 2
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
what does it mean?

Comment: oh, is there any NUMBER type column in the FINAL table? (except the id column)

Comment: Ya. The C_PHONE column is NUMBER

Comment: ok, so the value `01722. 00000` is not a number, and probably fails to insert into it. Check the original table (`INTER`) to see what is the column type for the `C_PHONE` field.

Comment: I changed the datatype. It worked. Thanks. What if I want only DISTINCT records from INTER? I means I cant say DISTINCT in SELECT statement as MIGR_SQ cant be distinct.

Comment: Use this select query instead: `SELECT M_SQ.NEXTVAL, C_NAME, C_PHONE, C_ADDRESS FROM (SELECT DISTINCT C_NAME, C_PHONE, C_ADDRESS FROM INTER);`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Also, the NEXTVAL of sequences always refers to the next number from previously used values. Can I set it to 1 every time I run the procedure?

Comment: yes, but this is tricky http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a stored proc - you can just run the command as is:

```
INSERT INTO FINAL (C_ID,C_NAME,C_PHONE,C_ADDRESS) SELECT M_SQ.NEXTVAL,C_NAME,C_PHONE,C_ADDRESS FROM INTER; 
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I know i can run the command but its a part of requirement and hence I have to make use of procedure. It gets compiled and it runs succesfully when I call it. However, the table FINAL is still empty.