# Invalid numbers on sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

When I created a sequence for a table `article`, it's started from 17 not 1

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_article START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER auto_article BEFORE insert ON article
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT seq_article.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.id_article FROM dual;
END;
/
```

I tried to delete all rows and creat other data, this time it's started from 19. How can I fix that?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand the problem.

- A sequence generates unique values.  Unless you set the sequence to `CYCLE` and you exceed the `MAXVALUE` (not realistically possible given the definition you posted) or you manually [reset the sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle) (say, by setting the `INCREMENT BY` to -16, fetching a `nextval`, and then setting the `INCREMENT BY` back to 1), it won't ever generate a value of `1` a second time.  Deleting the data has no impact on the next `id_article` that will be generated.
- A sequence-generated column will have gaps.  Whether because the sequence cache gets aged out of the shared pool or because a transaction was rolled back, not every value will end up in the table.  If you really need gap-free values, you cannot use a sequence.  Of course, that means that you would have to serialize `INSERT` operations which will massively decrease the scalability of your application.

Comment: Well, the problem it increments by 1 but generates automatically the first number!

Comment: @Khan, are you trying to do something meaningful with these numbers?  Generally, all you want is uniqueness.

Comment: @Khan - I'm still not understanding the problem.  The first call to `nextval` did not return 17, it returned 1 if the sequence definition is what you say it is.  It is entirely possible that the value of 1 was somehow lost because the session that retrieved that value didn't persist it to the database (perhaps there was an error, for example), because the session rolled back the `INSERT`, or for some other reason.  Since you don't use a sequence when you need gap-free values, though, it shouldn't matter if there is no row with an `id_article` of 12.

Comment: @Khan - But what?  Did you intend that comment to end where it ended?

Comment: But it's not the case! I can't understand why it returns a random number for the first row

Comment: @Khan - That seems highly unlikely (and I assume that you really don't mean random).  If I run the code you posted, the first `nextval` will be 1.  If you are seeing some other behavior, you must be doing something that you haven't mentioned here.