# I would just like to know if it is possible to a sequence to reset back to its original start with value? in Oracle

Tags: oracle

***Query:***

select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('SEQUENCE','SEQ') from dual

***Result doesnt give me the original start with value, it only gives the current value***

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "SEQ"  MINVALUE 2 MAXVALUE 50 INCREMENT BY 7 START WITH 9 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle

Comment: @Ryan This is not a duplicate, please vote to reopen.  This question is asking how to find the *original* start with value.  This is not the same as simply resetting the value.

Comment: Sorry, @jonearles I didn't vote to close this and can't vote to re-open (I generally object to the prolific heavy-handed closing of questions on SO)

Comment: This looks like an interesting question but it's virtually impossible to reopen a question here.  If you really need an answer, either ask to have it re-opened on Meta or re-ask the question with an explanation of why it is *not* a duplicate of other similar-sounding questions.