# automating rollback script oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, release-management

When releasing database code to non-development databases , I use such approach - I create release sqlplus script that runs multiple create table/view/sequence/package/etc statements in a sequence. I also should create rollback script which performs drop and other statements if would be needed during deployment or further use. But it is quite annoying always to create rollback scripts manually. I.E. - when I put

```
alter table table_a add column some_column number(5);
```

into release script. I have to put

```
alter table table_a drop column some_column;
```

into the rollback script. And vice-versa.

Is there way to optimize(or semi-optimize) it? Maybe some there are some Java/Python/etc libraries that allow to parse ddl statements into logical parts?

Maybe there are some better approaches for release/rollback pl/sql code?

Comment: Have you looked at Oracle flashback?  I think you can undo DDL, but not 100% sure.  Maybe someone can comment on that.

Comment: Flashback, how I understand, is for a bit different solutions. It rolls back the data also. I.E. - a had made a release (added column to table), then user had inserted some data into this table and then user decided that functionality based on this column should be released not right now, but in later releases. If I use flashback - the data that user have inserted would be removed along with the column that I added. But I want just to drop the column, leaving the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DBMS_METADATA_DIFF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_metadiff.htm#CHEGCGCB) and a few metadata queries can automate this process.

This example demonstrates 6 types of changes: 1) adding a column 2) incrementing a sequence 3) dropping a table 4) creating a table 5) changing a view 6) allocating an extent.

```
create table user1.add_column(id number);
create table user2.add_column(id number);
alter table user2.add_column add some_column number(5);

create sequence user1.increment_sequence nocache;
select user1.increment_sequence.nextval from dual;
select user1.increment_sequence.nextval from dual;
create sequence user2.increment_sequence nocache;
select user2.increment_sequence.nextval from dual;

create table user1.drop_table(id number);

create table user2.create_table(id number);

create view user1.change_view as select 1 a from dual;
create view user2.change_view as select 2 a from dual;

create table user1.allocate_extent(id number);
create table user2.allocate_extent(id number);
insert into user2.allocate_extent values(1);
rollback;
```

You are correct that DBMS_METADATA_DIFF  does not work for `CREATE` or `DROP`.  Trying to diff an object that only exists in one schema will generate an error message
like this:

```
ORA-31603: object "EXTRA_TABLE" of type TABLE not found in schema "USER1"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 7944
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA_DIFF", line 712
```

However, dropping and adding objects may be easy to script with the following:

```
--Dropped objects
select 'DROP '||object_type||' USER1.'||object_name v_sql
from
(
    select object_name, object_type from dba_objects where owner = 'USER1'
    minus
    select object_name, object_type from dba_objects where owner = 'USER2'
);

V_SQL
-----
DROP TABLE USER1.DROPPED_TABLE

--Added objects
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type, object_name, 'USER2') v_sql
from
(
    select object_name, object_type from dba_objects where owner = 'USER2'
    minus
    select object_name, object_type from dba_objects where owner = 'USER1'
);

V_SQL
-----
  CREATE TABLE "USER2"."CREATED_TABLE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS"
```

The alters can be handled with a SQL statement like this:

```
select object_name, object_type, dbms_metadata_diff.compare_alter(
    object_type => object_type,
    name1 => object_name,
    name2 => object_name,
    schema1 => 'USER2',
    schema2 => 'USER1',
    network_link1 => 'MYSELF',
    network_link2 => 'MYSELF') difference
from
(
    select object_name, object_type from dba_objects where owner = 'USER1'
    intersect
    select object_name, object_type from dba_objects where owner = 'USER2'
) objects;


OBJECT_NAME         OBJECT_TYPE    DIFFERENCE
-----------         -----------    ----------
ADD_COLUMN          TABLE          ALTER TABLE "USER2"."ADD_COLUMN" DROP ("SOME_COLUMN")
ALLOCATE_EXTENT     TABLE          -- ORA-39278: Cannot alter table with segments to segment creation deferred.
CHANGE_VIEW         VIEW           -- ORA-39308: Cannot alter attribute of view: SUBQUERY
INCREMENT_SEQUENCE  SEQUENCE       ALTER SEQUENCE "USER2"."INCREMENT_SEQUENCE" RESTART START WITH 3
```

Some notes about these results:

- ADD_COLUMN works as expected.
- ALLOCATE_EXTENT is probably a false positive, I doubt you care about deferred segment creation.  It is very unlikely to affect your system.
- CHANGE_VIEW does not work at all.  But as with the previous metadata queries, there should be a relatively easy way to build this script using DBA_VIEWS.
- INCREMENT_SEQUENCE works too well.  Most of the time an application does not care about the sequence values.  But sometimes when things get out of sync you need to change them.  This `RESTART START WITH` syntax can be very helpful.  You don't need to drop or re-create the indexes, or mess with the `increment by` multiple times.  This syntax is not in the [12c manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_2013.htm#i2228022).  In fact, I cannot find it anywhere on Google.  Looks like this package is using undocumented features.

Some other notes:

- The package can be very slow sometimes.
- If network links on the server are a problem you will need to run it through a local instance with links to both servers.
- There may be false positives.  Sometimes it returns a row with just a space in it.

It is possible to fully automate this process.  But based on the issues above, and my experience with *all* such automated tools, you should not trust it 100%.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it. Sure rollback scripts review should always take place. I'm talking only about  automating it a bit. How I see from the documentation of DBMS_METADATA_DIFF, it can handle only alter statements, am I right? And what about handing create/drop table /sequence/view etc? Have you used it in real life release situations?

Comment: See my modified answer.  I think using this package and a few other metadata queries can get you what you want.  4 queries can get you about 99% of the way there.  But that last 1% may be insanely difficult.  I've used this feature on a real system, but only to verify known changes.  I have never ran the actual script.

Comment: Thank you! It is not exactly what I was looking for, because there is no procedure for all cases and you also should decide what to use (I think it is not easier than writing rollback manually). But as there are no other answers it seems to me that it's the only one possible variant. I think the only possible way to do this - is to write application that parses input - decides what type of ddl is it  and generates roolback statement.