# Oracle DB comparison

Tags: database, oracle, comparison

We have Oracle databases for different environment such as Development, System Integration Test, User Acceptance Test and Production. We want to make sure the DB objects such as tables, index, stored procedure etc. are synchronized after each deployment, so we are carrying out some evaluation on DB comparison tools.

But as our budget is really tight, we may eventually need to find a solution that is free. 
We don't need to know which line of s.p. is different from the other. We just need to know what table / column / stored. proc. is missing,

Does Oracle come with some tools that help us perform this task? Can we write some scripts that can help us find out the difference between Oracle databases?

Comment: http://www.diffkit.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [automating rollback script oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574971/automating-rollback-script-oracle)

Comment: SQL developer has a "Diff Wizard" tool which might do the job for you. Otherwise, I'd generate a script to run on each environment that simply checks the contents of USER_OBJECTS and USER_TAB_COLUMNS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comparision tool comparedb from ems which i have used in previous project.

There are other ways like script and a tool TOAD which can also be used. Additional info.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/361526