# Generate upgrade script to ALTER TABLE based on CREATE TABLE statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl, oracle11gr2

Is it possible in Oracle to generate a bunch of `ALTER TABLE` statements based on existing table in schema plus `CREATE TABLE` statement with newer definition of that table?

Let's say I have a schema with some previous version of an application. I have an installation script for newest version of the application. The script creates all tables and sequences from scratch performing `CREATE TABLE` (and probably `CREATE SEQUENCE`) statements.

I'd like to update the schema to the newest version of the application without loosing any data (e.g. without performing `DROP TABLE`).

Is it possible with using of standard Oracle 11gR2 or third party components?

Comment: There is no tool I would trust 100% to do this.  But a few small scripts using DBMS_METADATA_DIFF may get you most of the way.  Depending on what exactly you're looking for, this question be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19574971/409172).

Comment: @Jon Heller isn't DBMS_METADATA_DIFF extra cost option?

Comment: @Politank-Z, my question is not about migration, but rather about automation of normal installation. I saw the question, but it asks rather about comparing two schemas (source and target) whereas my quesion asks about comparing a schema versus `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @ibre5041 Yes, it requires the Oracle Change Management Pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try CORT : [www.cort.tech](http://www.cort.tech)
https://github.com/cort-master/cort

It's free

Comment: If you have any questions how to use it or how to organize your source code please contact me by email from the website

Comment: Thanks! CORT looks very promising, the idea of handling modifications through `DDL TRIGGER`s is brilliant.

Comment: that link seems to be down seven years later.

Comment: I have updated the link now and added link to source code on github

Answer (score 0):

You can create a procedure in PLSQL to:

- create new table when it not exists in new DB
- alter table when it exists, feeding it with ALL_TAB_COLUMNS

Comment: This is not an option, because I'd have to parse CREATE TABLE statement to get the list of missing columns.

Comment: You can't find missing columns with compare of ALL_TAB_COLUMNS ?

Comment: I cannot find missing columns without executing my `CREATE TABLE` on some additional schema first. It could be costly, and it cannot be done separately for each `CREATE TABLE` because of possible `FOREIGN KEY`s constraints. I have to run the entire installation script first over auxiliary database, and I'd like to avoid this step.