# Alter database based on create table statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`) USING BTREE,
  FULLTEXT KEY `dgd` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=150 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then a newer version of the table is available

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`) USING BTREE,
  FULLTEXT KEY `dgd` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=150 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Is there any way to generate `ALTER` statements to adapt to the new changes? I want to be able to upgrade to the newer version automatically but keep table data.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678190/generate-upgrade-script-to-alter-table-based-on-create-table-statement-in-oracle) which seems to be an oracle equivalent of exactly what I'm looking for - `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE`

Comment: 'a newer version of the table is available' What do you mean by that?

Comment: @e4c5 that the table was changed by the creator of the program (a newer version) and I'd like to keep my version up to date.

Comment: If you are talking of some third party software, they will surely have built in migrations.

Comment: @e4c5 well how about if there aren't, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: in that case this becomes an off topic question because you are essentially asking if there is a tool to compare two table schemas

Comment: @e4c5 what do you mean? Where is this appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You can alter tables after creation, in your case to create a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN Name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
```

Comment: I want to be able to do this automatically, I was just giving an example, obviously I don't know what the changes will be and I don't want to be doing this by hand.

Comment: short of using a program to do a schema compare I wouldn't know a way to do this automatically, for instance in MySQL WorkBench

Comment: Or have a look at the RedGate SQL Compare tools they are good but also $$$

Answer (score 0):

The above answer definitely works, but it might lock your table and make your table unavailable if your table is too large. If you don't want downtime, you can use pt-online-schema to do this.

make a shell script out of the below script and execute it

```
    #!/bin/bash

    DBUSER=username
    DBPASS=password
    DBSCHEMA=db_name
    TABLE=table_name

    ALTER_SQL="modify column destination_url text;" #what you want to modify or add

    pt-online-schema-change \
            --alter "$ALTER_SQL" \
            --charset utf8 \
            --nocheck-replication-filters \
            --chunk-size 10000 \
            --critical-load Threads_running=10000 \
            --nodrop-new-table \
            --max-load Threads_running=50 \
            --progress time,60 \
            --recursion-method none \
            --statistics \
            --pid $HOST.pid \
            --host $HOST \
            --execute \
            u=$DBUSER,p=$DBPASS,D=$DBSCHEMA,t=$TABLE >> output.log 2>&1 &
```