# How to generate DDL for deltas only between two different versions of a schema?

Tags: oracle, version-control, oracle11g, schema, ddl

I have read both TOAD and Liquibase can do this but I don't have licenses. We have access to OEM and are using JDeveloper/SQLDeveloper but neither seem to have a tool to generate the DDL for deltas only between two schemas.

This is to solve schema versioning issues, where we have vx.x of a schema in the test environment and vx.y in development, and desire to generate DDL deltas between (x.x-x.y) in order to generate and check in deployment scripts.

Currently I am managing all of this manually by getting scripts from developers and building one single update script by hand.

Comment: You indicate that you are using SQL Developer.  Have you looked at it's database diff feature (Tools-->Database Diff)?  If you are looking to compare specific objects you can use it's cart tool to create two carts containing the objects to compare, then do a diff between them.

Comment: Sort of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19574971/409172    Although personally I prefer to do this by hand.  With one-step deployments and local instances for developers it would be relatively easy to generate these scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use package dbms_metadata_diff.
Example

```
   select DBMS_METADATA_DIFF.COMPARE_ALTER('TABLE','COUNTRIES','COUNTRIES2') from dual
```

Comment: I don't think this is what Alexx is looking for.  She wants the diff between two schemas not two tables in the same schema.  A better example would have been this: `DBMS_METADATA_DIFF.COMPARE_ALTER('TABLE','COUNTRIES','COUNTRIES','SCHEMA1','SCHEMA2')` but this only works for objects that exist in both schemas.  The OP will still have to identify objects that need to be created in or dropped from the target schema separately.

Comment: This is helpful in that I could script around this statement by comparing all objects that I'm interested in.   I would still need to make sure everything is generated in the proper order (e.g. a column is added and then a new constraint on that column). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did find the awesome diff utility in SQLDeveloper, which is hugely helpful (and not so much in OEM?).

I was ultimately looking for a handy way to generate the delta DDL. For example, SCHEMA_2.TABLE_A is (foo number(22), bar varchar2(100)), and SCHEMA_1.TABLE_A is (foo number(22), bar varchar(100), baz CLOB). Looking for a utility to generate

ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_1.TABLE_A add column (baz CLOB)

I'm guessing it's a pipe dream to get that 'for free' in the tools I have. :)

We're using Flyway for our developers, and I guess I'm going to just have to manually manage the migrations for now.

Thanks to everyone for the great suggestions!

Cheers,
Alexx