# Oracle update sequence value

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle 11, and using a  query/queries (no stored procedure) I want to to update my sequencers value to:

```
 biggest primary key in table + 1
```

This is what I have but couldnt combine these two:

```
select max("ID") from  ACCOUNTS;    

ALTER SEQUENCE SEQ_ACCOUNTS INCREMENT BY "how to use here the max + 1";
```

Comment: You can't do this in a single query.  You could execute a series of SQL statements.  Or you could put that series of SQL statements in a stored procedure or anonymous PL/SQL block.

Comment: @Justin Cave it does not has to be single query, I just want it without a stored procedure

Comment: Is an anonymous PL/SQL block acceptable?  If so, just take the stored procedure and replace the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <<procedure name>> AS` with `DECLARE`.

Comment: @Justin Cave without using stored procedure is it that difficult to use a value/varaible I want in my query? it thought it is very simple with some variable assigmnets

Comment: As I said, if an anonymous PL/SQL block is acceptable, you just need to make a trivial modification to the stored procedure to be able to use PL/SQL variables.

Comment: @Justin Cave I dont know what is a  anonymous PL/SQL block neither how to write a oracle sql procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [example of a stored procedure that resets a sequence value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle) can be found in another StackOverflow thread.  It sounds like an anonymous PL/SQL block would be acceptable to you just not a stored procedure.  In that case, you can make some minor modifications...

```
declare
  l_current_max number;
  l_current_seq number;
  l_tmp         number;
begin
  select max( id )
    into l_current_max
    from accounts;

  select seq_accounts.nextval
    into l_current_seq
    from dual;

  -- Set the nextval of the sequence to 0
  execute immediate
    'alter sequence seq_accounts increment by -' || l_current_seq || ' minvalue 0';

  -- Fetch a value of 0
  execute immediate
    'select seq_accounts.nextval from dual' 
    into l_tmp;

  -- Set the nextval of the sequence to the current max
  execute immediate
    'alter sequence seq_accounts increment by ' || l_current_max || ' minvalue 0';

  -- Fetch the current max
  execute immediate
    'select seq_accounts.nextval from dual' 
    into l_tmp;

  -- Set the nextval of the sequence to the current max + 1
  execute immediate
    'alter sequence seq_accounts increment by 1 minvalue 0';
end;
```

You can do the same thing with a single step rather than setting the sequence to 0 and then to the current max in separate steps but I find it a bit clearer to do it this way.

Comment: @Spring There is no function to set the value of a sequence, so you have to do it in a roundabout way where you change the step size for the sequence.