# setval - FROM keyword found in the wrong location

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a sequence that starts from the max id in my table.

I went off this previously asked question 
[How to create sequence using starting value from query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411113/how-to-create-sequence-using-starting-value-from-query)

This is the sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE q9_seq;

SELECT setval('q9_seq', (SELECT MAX(department_id) FROM hr_departments));
```

The result im getting is :

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected error.

Comment: That link is to a Postgresql question.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare
v_num number;
begin
    select nvl(max(value), 0) + 1
    into v_num
    from table;

    execute immediate 'create sequence drop_me_seq start with ' || v_num;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use client-specific functionality like substitution variables for this, e.g. in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer:

```
column v_start new_value v_start

select nvl(max(department_id), 0) + 1 as v_start from hr_departments;

create sequence q9_seq start with &v_start;

old:create sequence q9_seq start with &v_start
new:create sequence q9_seq start with 43

Sequence Q9_SEQ created.

select q9_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        43
```

or you could alter an existing sequence to skip numbers, or call `nextval` until you reach the existing maximum ([as here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27570176/266304)).

Or you could use a simple anonymous block:

```
declare
  l_start number;
begin
  select nvl(max(department_id), 0) + 1 into l_start from hr_departments;

  execute immediate 'create sequence q9_seq start with ' || l_start;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

select q9_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        43
```

The dynamic SQL statement is generated the same as with the substitution variable approach, as `create sequence q9_seq start with 43`.

(Both of these assume your table's highest current value is 42...)