# Reset Oracle Sequence to have MIN VALUE = 1 and STARTING number from 1

Tags: oracle, sequence, reset

I have a problem resetting Oracle Sequence to have MIN VALUE = 1 and starting next number used is 1.

I have followed through the answer of this question:
[How do I reset a sequence in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle)

```
   create or replace procedure reset_seq( p_seq_name in varchar2 ) is
        l_val number; 
begin
        execute immediate
        'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;

        execute immediate
        'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name || ' increment by -' || l_val || 
                                                              ' minvalue 0';

        execute immediate
        'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;

        execute immediate
        'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name || ' increment by 1 minvalue 0'; 
end;
```

But, the problem is the code above is resetting the sequence with min value = 0, and the next val to be used is 2.

Is it possible to set the min_value = 1, and nextval to be 1, after the reset is done?

I tried to set it but getting the error mentioning approximately as below:

> The current value cannot be higher then Minimum Value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the min value = 1, and next val to be 1, after the reset is done?

You could do it in two steps:

- increment_by value one less than the current value of the sequence.
- reset increment_by back to 1.

The logic is that, *you shouldn't decrement the sequence back to zero*, since the **minvalue** you want is `1`, so, the **nextval cannot be less than the minval**.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE s START WITH 20 MINVALUE 0 INCREMENT BY 1;

Sequence created.

SQL> SELECT s.nextval FROM dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        20

SQL> ALTER SEQUENCE s INCREMENT BY -19 MINVALUE 1;

Sequence altered.

SQL> SELECT s.nextval FROM dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

SQL> ALTER SEQUENCE s INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1;

Sequence altered.

SQL> SELECT s.nextval FROM dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         2

SQL> SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM user_sequences WHERE sequence_name='S';

 MIN_VALUE INCREMENT_BY
---------- ------------
         1            1
```

So, the **min_value** and **increment_by** is now **reset** to `1` respectively. The **nextvalue** could be 1 only once before you reset the **increment_by** to `1` again.

So, I don't see any practical use of what you want to achieve. However, it could be done as demonstrated above.

To implement the above logic in your procedure, do as following:

**Setup**

```
SQL> DROP SEQUENCE S;

Sequence dropped.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE s START WITH 20 MINVALUE 0 INCREMENT BY 1;

Sequence created.

SQL> SELECT s.nextval FROM dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        20
```

Modify your **procedure** as:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE reset_seq(
  2      p_seq_name IN VARCHAR2 )
  3  IS
  4    l_val NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;
  7    l_val := l_val - 1;
  8    dbms_output.put_line('l_val = '||l_val);
  9    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter sequence ' ||
 10                       p_seq_name || ' increment by -' || l_val || ' minvalue 1';
 11    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;
 12    dbms_output.put_line('1st Nextval is '||l_val);
 13    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name ||
 14                      ' increment by 1 MINVALUE 1';
 15    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual' INTO l_val;
 16    dbms_output.put_line('2nd Nextval is '||l_val);
 17  END;
 18  /

Procedure created.

SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> EXEC reset_seq('S');
l_val = 20
1st Nextval is 1
2nd Nextval is 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM user_sequences where sequence_name='S';

 MIN_VALUE INCREMENT_BY
---------- ------------
         1            1
```

As I said, *I don't see any practical use of it*. Your **nextval** is practically usable only from `2`. When it is `1`, you need to do an **ALTER SEQUENCE** once again to reset the **increment_by** back to `1`.

Comment: Thanks! I would try this one at soonest possible time!