# How to reset identity columns in Oracle (PL SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to write a script to reset all auto-incrementing fields in the database to 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295422/how-to-reset-identity-column-in-oracle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to reset Identity column in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295422/how-to-reset-identity-column-in-oracle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to share the solution to the problem.

To get a list of table names, I do the following:

```
SELECT T.TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS C
INNER JOIN ALL_TABLES T ON C.OWNER = T.OWNER AND C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
WHERE T.OWNER = 'SCHEME'
AND C.DATA_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL
```

Further in the loop, you can generate dynamic sql as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
MODIFY ID 
GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1);
```

And we execute the dynamic SQL line through `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Below is an example from my project:

```
PROCEDURE RESET_ALL_IDENTITY_COLUMNS IS
BEGIN
  FOR TABLES_WITH_IDENTITY IN (SELECT T.TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS C
                               INNER JOIN ALL_TABLES T ON C.OWNER = T.OWNER AND C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
                               WHERE T.OWNER = 'DZR'
                               AND C.DATA_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL)
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || TABLES_WITH_IDENTITY.TABLE_NAME || ' MODIFY ID GENERATED BY DEFAULT ' ||
                     'ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1)';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Good luck :)

Comment: your clause `AND C.DATA_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL` does not return only columns with identity but all columns with a default value.
The query for table with identity is :
`select * 
from all_tables T
where T.has_identity = 'YES'`