# ORA-32796: cannot update a generated always identity column

Tags: database, oracle, vb.net

I am converting some code from vb.net 2008 to vb.net 2019. I got some warnings in my code that the Oracle reference I was using would be outdated in future versions so I switched to a Oracle.ManagedDataAccess reference.

It seems I can read data but unfortunately when I try to write data, I am running into issues I didn't have before. When I try to update an existing record in my Oracle database, I am getting this error:

ORA-32796: cannot update a generated always identity column

If I change my query to only include the fields I want to update then I get this error:

Dynamic SQL generation failed. No key information found

The second error makes sense but not the first. It seems like there's something about my ID column the new code doesn't like. I'm not a db expert or anything but I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like table's ID column was created as

```
id NUMBER GENERATED     ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                        ------
```

If it was

```
id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
                    ----------
```

then you, I presume, wouldn't get that error.

---

Anyway: it would help if you posted `CREATE TABLE` as well as DML you preformed against that table.

Comment: Why I am not getting that error in the other version of my code?

Comment: I really wouldn't know.

Comment: Here's a link to the table layout: 

https://i.imgur.com/KpwyqjL.png

The ID field is just a number that gets created with a trigger.

I don't see the Always as Identity you referred to.

Comment: Please **do not post links** to tables structure or code. Post both as text.  We cannot answer questions about table structure or code without seeing the structure or code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the same as one of my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295422/how-to-reset-identity-column-in-oracle/55274611#55274611)

If you have generated/created the table with scripts like this:

```
ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
```

Then it will not allow you to update or insert the value of the ID column.

if you have generated like this, you could insert or update

```
ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
```

However, by altering the table you can achieve this

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] MODIFY ID GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH LIMIT VALUE);
```

and after updating or inserting you can go back to the previous state by running the following script

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] MODIFY ID GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH LIMIT VALUE);
```