# How do I correctly set the GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY sequence after inserting manual ids?

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key, identity-column

I have a table with a primary key sequence using the newer `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` feature:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    data VARCHAR
);
```

I then give the table a few values to begin with, overriding the sequence:

```sql
INSERT INTO test(id,data) VALUES (3,'something');
INSERT INTO test(id,data) VALUES (6,'something else');
```

Now if I add a few more values, letting the sequence do its thing:

```sql
INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES ('whatever');
INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES ('stuff');
INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES ('etc');
```

… I get an error:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (FIDDLE_CEYTNFUWNIDRFXSPTDWJ.SYS_C0054804) violated

OK, I understand the error: apparently the sequence starts at the beginning and begins to overlap with existing values.

How do I correctly set the sequence after the initial `INSERT`?

I have a fiddle at: https://dbfiddle.uk/MtPocwBq

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There was a useful solution for PostgreSQL, but I now need one for Oracle. I’ve changed the tag accordingly.

Comment: [how to reset Identity column in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295422/how-to-reset-identity-column-in-oracle)

Comment: 1. `generated always` at create time. 2. `alter table modify id generated ... ` as in linked question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to reset Identity column in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295422/how-to-reset-identity-column-in-oracle)

Comment: @PonderStibbons The accepted answer method 2 appears to do the job. Not the same question, but the answer did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is:

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY ID GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH LIMIT VALUE);
```

Description in Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#CJAEHCBE):

> START WITH LIMIT VALUE, which is specific to identity_options, can
> only be used with ALTER TABLE MODIFY. If you specify START WITH LIMIT
> VALUE, then Oracle Database locks the table and finds the maximum
> identity column value in the table (for increasing sequences) or the
> minimum identity column value (for decreasing sequences) and assigns
> the value as the sequence generator's high water mark. The next value
> returned by the sequence generator will be the high water mark +
> INCREMENT BY integer for increasing sequences, or the high water mark - INCREMENT BY integer for decreasing sequences.

And your modified [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LMVKbfGV).

Answer (score 0):

Reset the generated ID sequence using:

```
alter table test modify (id generated as identity (start with 7));
```

See modified [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DM2ORwu8).