# Update existing sequence values form starting with 1?

Tags: sql, nuodb

Can I update existing sequence values form staring with 1.

Example : In table one sequence column starting the sequence form 5001 but i want change that value form starting with 1.

If it is possible how can approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create id with AUTO\_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset a sequence in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle)

Comment: How are you going to handle it when your sequence generates values you already have in the table (e.g. 5001)? Or do you mean you want to update all existing values in that column and this is nothing to do with [an Oracle sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/schemaob.htm#CNCPT88878)? (In which case... is the column a primary key? And if these are synthetic anyway why update?)

Comment: I am using NuoDB database, The column contains duplicate sequence numbers already so i want to make it is non duplicates numbers.Finally i want to reset the whole sequence from starting with 1 in that column.

Comment: So why have you tagged your question with [oracle11g]?

Comment: NuoDB is also using SQL only so based on that i have expected get any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think your easiest path is to delete the table and reload. Before reloading specify a primary key. This will prevent duplicates getting inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the sequence starting value with [ALTER SEQUENCE](http://doc.nuodb.com/Latest/Default.htm#ALTER-SEQUENCE.htm).  However, setting the start point back causes conflicts with existing values in the table.  Also NuoDB does not necessarily handout sequence numbers in sequence.  Given that it's a distributed database,  a sequential number generator would greatly affect performance as each TE would need to check some master for next sequence number.   What NuoDB does is handout a sequence block which the TE uses and then request another block when it runs out.   If the TE is shut down and restarted it will get a new block.