# SQL CREATE SEQUENCE based on a combination of date and counter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle SQL:

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production              0 
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                                    0 
CORE    12.1.0.2.0  Production                                                            0 
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                            0 
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

I need help figuring out how to create a sequence for a key field below:

I have a table with a field named MY_ID.

MY_ID needs to be automatically generated using sequence when a record is inserted.

The rule for the sequence is a combination of a string prefix, an counter increment by 1 per day and reset at midnight, and the date.

for example:
on Sept 10, we inserted 2 records, then the MY_ID should be:

```
PREFIX_01_20170910
PREFIX_02_20170910
```

on Sept 11 :

```
PREFIX_01_20170911
PREFIX_02_20170911
PREFIX_03_20170911
```

on Sept 12, the whole table might look like this

```
PREFIX_01_20170910
PREFIX_02_20170910
PREFIX_01_20170911
PREFIX_02_20170911
PREFIX_03_20170911
PREFIX_01_20170912
```

so far, all i can do with the sequence is increment by 1 regardless of the date:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_MY_TABLE INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1 NOCACHE;
```

and the trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER MY_TABLE_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT ON MY_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING AND :NEW.MY_ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT SEQ_MY_TABLE .NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.MY_ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can probably dream up a scheme to generate this `PREFIX_nn_date` key that will appear to work in your development environment, but I'm going to give you a bit of unwanted advice: don't waste your time on it. Make your primary key a simple NUMBER column, populate it from a sequence, and move on. Once your code hits production, where many more users will be banging on your table simultaneously, your carefully crafted scheme to generate that `PREFIX_nn_date` key is likely to fail - and the more band-aids you throw at it to fix the problems the worse it's going to become.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Bob for your advise. However in this situation, only <= 20 records will be inserted per year, i think it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the `TRIGGER` as follows. Since you need each digit in the sequence as 01,02,03 attached to your prefix, I have used `fm` specifier in `TO_CHAR` with `'00'`. If the total inserts per day exceeds 99 , you need to use `fm000`

```
create or replace TRIGGER MY_TABLE_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT ON MY_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING AND :NEW.MY_ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT 'PREFIX_'||TO_CHAR(SEQ_MY_TABLE.NEXTVAL,'fm00')||'_'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD') INTO :NEW.MY_ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
```

**Note**: To suggest a good practice, I do not recommend this to be used as your `PRIMARY KEY`. It would be better to simply make the sequence `PRIMARY KEY`  in all your application code while populating the records.

Comment: but this trigger does not reset SEQ_MY_TABLE.NEXTVAL right? if I insert 1 records today, I will get PREFIX_01_20170927 , If i insert another record tomorrow I will get PREFIX_02_20170928, is there a way to reset the NEXTVAL so that i will get PREFIX_01_20170928 tomorrow?

Comment: No to do that call the reset procedure described in this link  at 12:00 am from scheduler. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Bob Jarvis's answer, you can always create your string when you need it.  Here is a simple example.

```
with records as (
select 1 id, to_date('20170901', 'yyyymmdd') theDate
from dual
union
select 2 id, to_date('20170901', 'yyyymmdd') theDate
from dual
union
select 3 id, to_date('20170902', 'yyyymmdd') theDate
from dual

)

select 'prefix_' ||  
to_char(theDate, 'yyyymmdd') || '_' || 
to_char( rank() over (partition by theDate order by id)) prefix
from records
```

returns:

```
prefix_20170901_1                                        
prefix_20170901_2                                        
prefix_20170902_1
```

I don't do that much oracle work, but if you are going to do this repeatedly, you might want to incorporate this logic into a function or view.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way is to recreate sequence every midnight via job. But using sequences is not a good idea. I think this ID is important for you, but sequence can cache some values, some values can be missing. So you'll get:

```
PREFIX_01_20170910
PREFIX_02_20170910
PREFIX_04_20170910
PREFIX_07_20170910
```

...
and so on. For example you had "cache 10", you inserted 2 records and quited, or did rollback, or something else.

Use just number for increment field and calc this fake ID.

Comment: you are right! this is not a reliable method. I should probably generate this ID in the back end by query the table and count the record that has current date , and append prefix and date to generate that ID instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can create function like below to get new id and use it in the insert query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_GETID (P_DT IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
V_NEW_ID VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
SELECT 'PREFIX_' || COUNT(*)+1 ||'_' || P_DT INTO V_NEW_ID FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE MY_ID LIKE   'PREFIX%'||P_DT;
RETURN V_NEW_ID;
END;
```

then

```
 insert into my_table(my_id , ...) values(F_GETID('20170927'),...);
```