# Procedure add plus one (+1) everty time is called in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to do a procedure that add plus 1 to the previous value every time its is called in PL/SQL language. But I don't know how to do that.

I mean, if the procedure is call "plus1":

First execution:

```
exec plus1
```

will return value 1.

Second execution:

```
exec plus1
```

will return value 2.

And go on

Comment: Better create a sequence in the procedure and increment the sequence by 1.

Comment: Is the increment persistent across sessions or is it just for one session?

Comment: Just for one session.

Comment: Just for session - in the second part of my question. There was an error, I corrected it a minute ago. Now the code is correct.

Comment: You ask for a procedure that "returns" something. Such a thing does not exist; either it is a procedure, which increments the value (which you can then use wherever you need it) but the procedure itself doesn't "return" anything, or it is a function. Which do you actually need? How do you plan to use this whole mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to create a sequence, as noticed in comments:

```
create sequence my_seq;
```

To call the sequence in PL/SQL:

```
my_var := my_seq.nextval;
```

To call in SQL:

```
select t.*, my_seq.nextval from table t;
```

In the SQL query, a new value will be generated for each line.

If you don't need a sequence, and you don't need to store the value between sessions, create a package:

```
create or replace package my_package as

function get_next_value return number;

end my_package;
/

create or replace package body my_package as

current_num number := 0;

function get_next_value return number is
begin
  current_num := current_num + 1;
  return current_num;
end;

end my_package;
/
```

And then call `my_package.get_next_value`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you need. Here is one approach, assuming you need a session variable, initialized to zero at the start of the session, which you can call as needed, and is increased only when a procedure is executed. This is different from a function that increments the variable and returns it at the same time.

If you need to access the variable in SQL (rather than just in PL/SQL), you need to write a wrapper function that returns the value; I included the wrapper function in the code below.

```
create or replace package silly_p as
  v number := 0;
  function show_v return number;
  procedure increment_v;
end;
/

create or replace package body silly_p as
  function show_v return number is
    begin
      return v;
    end show_v;
  procedure increment_v is
    begin
      v := v+1;
    end increment_v;
end silly_p;
/
```

Here is a SQL*Session demonstrating the compilation of this package and then its use - I access the variable both through SQL SELECT and from PL/SQL (with DBMS_OUTPUT) to demonstrate both access methods. Notice how the value is unchanged between calls to the procedure, and increases by one every time the procedure is executed.

```
SQL> create or replace package silly_p as
  2    v number := 0;
  3    function show_v return number;
  4    procedure increment_v;
  5  end;
  6  /

Package created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
SQL>
SQL> create or replace package body silly_p as
  2    function show_v return number is
  3      begin
  4        return v;
  5      end show_v;
  6    procedure increment_v is
  7      begin
  8        v := v+1;
  9      end increment_v;
 10  end silly_p;
 11  /

Package body created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> select silly_p.show_v from dual;

    SHOW_V
----------
         0

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> exec dbms_output.put_line(silly_p.v)
0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL> exec silly_p.increment_v

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
SQL> select silly_p.show_v from dual;

    SHOW_V
----------
         1

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.14
SQL> exec silly_p.increment_v

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.07
SQL> exec dbms_output.put_line(silly_p.v)
2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.07
SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question recently (have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380437/how-to-use-oracle-db-sequences-without-losing-the-next-sequence-number-in-case-o/49382283#49382283)); basically, you need to store *current* value somewhere (a table might be a good choice) and create a function (or, in your case, a procedure) that returns the next number.

How to convert the function I wrote to a procedure? Use it as a wrapper.

Here's the whole example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE broj (redni_br NUMBER NOT NULL);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_broj
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4     PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  5     l_redni_br   broj.redni_br%TYPE;
  6  BEGIN
  7         SELECT b.redni_br + 1
  8           INTO l_redni_br
  9           FROM broj b
 10     FOR UPDATE OF b.redni_br;
 11
 12     UPDATE broj b
 13        SET b.redni_br = l_redni_br;
 14
 15     COMMIT;
 16     RETURN (l_redni_br);
 17  EXCEPTION
 18     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 19     THEN
 20        LOCK TABLE broj IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
 21
 22        INSERT INTO broj (redni_br)
 23             VALUES (1);
 24
 25        COMMIT;
 26        RETURN (1);
 27  END f_get_broj;
 28  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE PROCEDURE p_get_Broj
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (f_get_broj);
  5  END;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> EXEC p_get_broj;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> EXEC p_get_broj;
2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC p_get_broj;
3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC p_get_broj;
4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Why are you complicating a simple stuff ? I mean the easier the code the better it is .

Comment: @XING, If you looked at the link (says "here" in my message), you'd see that I'm not the fan of such "solutions"; I use sequences and I'm happy with what they provide. There are, though, certain *business requirements* which say that values must be consecutive, no gaps, and that's what sequence can't always do (caching, rollbacks, ...). Code I posted is an excerpt from one of such procedures. Reading OP's question, I (maybe wrongly) understood that it is what he's asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a session a variable like mathguy's assumption above. You can try below code and understand how it works. Note that each DB session could have different value to the NUM_VAR variable in var_pkg package depending on how many times the procedure below was executed for each session.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE var_pkg
IS
    num_var NUMBER := 0;
    PROCEDURE set_num_var(p_number NUMBER);
    FUNCTION get_num_var RETURN NUMBER;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY var_pkg
IS
    PROCEDURE set_num_var(p_number NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        num_var := p_number;
    END;
    FUNCTION get_num_var RETURN NUMBER
    IS
     BEGIN
         RETURN num_var;
     END;
END;
/

CREATE PROCEDURE plus1
IS
    v_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_num := var_pkg.get_num_var + 1;
    var_pkg.set_num_var(v_num);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_num);
    END;
/
```

To run the procedure,

```
exec plus1;
```

or

```
BEGIN
    plus1;
END;
/
```

And in case you want to know the current value of the variable, you can query it using below code,

```
SELECT var_pkg.get_num_var 
  FROM dual;
```