# Reset a Sequence according to the year not by min or max value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, sequence

Create a sequence which will reset according to the year. 
Consider the sequence with 9 digit starts with 000000001 and max is 999999999.

Let Date is 30/12/2017 and seq is 000012849
So when the date is 01/01/2018, I want the seq to be 000000001.

Comment: you have a similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle

Comment: What do you mean by "reset according to the year"? Do you want the sequence to reset on Jan1?

Comment: @KaushikNayak yes, check the description again. I edited it. You will understand

Comment: @SudiptaMondal yep. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a recurring scheduled job that [resets the sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle?noredirect=1&lq=1) at midnight of 1st January each year.

Something like (assuming you have a `YOUR_SCHEMA.RESET_ANNUAL_SEQUENCE` procedure to perform the reset):

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name             => 'reset_annual_sequence_job',
    job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action           => 'BEGIN your_schema.reset_annual_sequence; END;',
    start_date           => ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YY' ), 12 ),
    repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=YEARLY; BYDATE=0101;', 
    enabled              =>  TRUE,
    comments             => 'Annual sequence reset'
  );
END;
/
```