# Q:reset sequnce, help around understanding

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sequence

I do not understand why there is a select statement in this code and why it has twice the alter sequence statement for increment by

I found this code on the site [asktom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1925376100346175343)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE pkg_seq AS
      PROCEDURE alterSequenceLast(
          sequenceName IN VARCHAR2,
          inc in integer);
END;
/

    CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY pkg_asktom AS
    PROCEDURE alterSequenceLast(
        sequenceName IN VARCHAR2,
        inc in integer)
    is
        stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
        l_n  number;
    begin
        BEGIN
            -- alter increment to inc
        stmt := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' ||  sequenceName ||' INCREMENT BY ' ||inc;
            dbms_output.put_line('Executing ''' || stmt || '''');
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
            -- read the next value
            stmt := 'SELECT ' || sequenceName || '.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';
            dbms_output.put_line('Executing ''' || stmt || '''');
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt into l_n;
            -- alter increment to 1
            stmt := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' ||  sequenceName ||' INCREMENT BY 1';
            dbms_output.put_line('Executing ''' || stmt || '''');
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
        END;
    end alterSequenceLast;
END;
/
```

After execution I get this

```
SQL>  exec pkg_seq.alterSequenceLast('acc_seq',1);
Executing 'ALTER SEQUENCE acc_seq INCREMENT BY 1'
Executing 'SELECT acc_seq.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL'
Executing 'ALTER SEQUENCE acc_seq INCREMENT BY 1'
```

I would do it this way, I would return the sequence to the beginning.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE pkg_seq AS
      PROCEDURE alterSequenceLast(
          sequenceName IN VARCHAR2,
          inc in integer);
END;
/

    CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY pkg_seq AS
    PROCEDURE alterSequenceLast(
        sequenceName IN VARCHAR2,
        inc in integer)
    is
        stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
        l_n  number;
    begin
        BEGIN
stmt := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' ||  sequenceName ||' restart start with ' ||inc;
         dbms_output.put_line('Executing ''' || stmt || '''');
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
         -- alter increment to 1
         stmt := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' ||  sequenceName ||' INCREMENT BY 1';
            dbms_output.put_line('Executing ''' || stmt || '''');
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
        END;
    end alterSequenceLast;
END;
/
```

Thaks advance, Petar.

Comment: `restart start with` is an undocumented feature which works in 12c. Read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19673327/7998591) . It says that *" it's an unsupported feature.. It's possible the command will disappear some day"*

Comment: Thanks, change the sequence acc_seq start with 1; this code does not work, what should I change?

Comment: *"This code does not work"*? What doesn't work? Is there an error or an unexpected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is for setting sequence to start from a new value.

For instance, suppose we have a table which usually has its ID generated by the sequence `our_seq` but for some reason we have loaded 10000 records without using the sequence. What happens if we insert a new record? As it stands `our_seq.nextval` will generate an ID which clashes with the key of a bulk-loaded record.

So, we need to adjust the value of the sequence. One way to do that would be to select `nextval` ten thousand times. Or we could

1. alter the sequence to increment by 10000
2. select nextval for the sequence once
3. alter the sequence to increment by 1 once again

The Tom Kyte package is a way of automating the second approach. Personally I would regard it as an interesting curio. If you need to undertake this operation often enough to need to automate it you probably should re-consider your data loading practices.

---

> could [we] increase the sequence for 10001 without select a statement?

No. The only supported way to do that would be to drop the sequence and re-create it with the required start with value. Dropping an object is more complicated because of grants, code invalidations, etc.

Supposing your interest is you have a sequence of say current value = 10001 and you want to reset it so it starts from 1 again you would pass a negative increment -10001. Be careful you don't decrement it past the `minvalue` (by default 1); the database won't warn you or hurl until you issue a `nextval` at which point it will tell you:

```
ORA-08004: sequence OUR_SEQ.NEXTVAL goes below MINVALUE and cannot be instantiated
```

Comment: Thanks, also he could increase the sequence for 10001 without select a statement

Comment: No. The only *supported* way to do that would be to drop the sequence and re-create it with the required `start with` value. Dropping an object is more complicated because of grants, code invalidations, etc