# Best strategy to reset Oracle sequence monthly

Tags: oracle, sequence, reset

I'm looking for the best strategy to reset a sequence which is used to generate unique keys. These keys are build using a prefix value, also generated by a combination of month and year values, like the following example:

2020060100000001 - Year(4d)Month(2d)Sequence(8d)

The sequence value must be restarted at the first second of each new month.

Is there any Oracle event that allows calling a function or procedure based in this situation to do this job?

Can anyone help me with opinions and experiences?

Thanks a lot!
Rodrigo

Comment: That is one something normally done with oracle sequences.  You could create a scheduled job to run on your required interval and either drop/re-create, or see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to set the value of a sequence you can use something like the following:

```
PROCEDURE SET_SEQUENCE(pinSequence_owner IN VARCHAR2,
                       pinSequence_name  IN VARCHAR2,
                       pinNew_next_value IN NUMBER,
                       pinDebug          IN BOOLEAN := FALSE)
IS
  strSQL               VARCHAR2(4000);
  nNext_number         NUMBER;
  nOriginal_increment  NUMBER;
  nNew_nextval         NUMBER;
  nNew_last_number     NUMBER;
BEGIN
  strSQL := 'SELECT s.LAST_NUMBER, INCREMENT_BY ' ||
              'FROM DBA_SEQUENCES s ' ||
              'WHERE s.SEQUENCE_OWNER = ''' || pinSequence_owner || ''' AND ' ||
                    's.SEQUENCE_NAME = ''' || pinSequence_name || '''';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strSQL INTO nNext_number, nOriginal_increment;

  -- Note that DBA_SEQUENCES.LAST_NUMBER represents the *next* number which will be
  -- returned by a call to NEXTVAL.

  IF pinNew_next_value NOT IN (nNext_number-1, nNext_number)
  THEN
    strSQL := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || pinSequence_owner || '.' || pinSequence_name ||
              ' INCREMENT BY ' || TO_CHAR(pinNew_next_value - nNext_number) || ' NOCACHE';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strSQL;

    strSQL := 'SELECT ' || pinSequence_owner || '.' || pinSequence_name || '.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strSQL INTO nNew_nextval;

    strSQL := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || pinSequence_owner || '.' || pinSequence_name ||
              ' INCREMENT BY ' || nOriginal_increment || ' NOCACHE';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strSQL;

    strSQL := 'SELECT s.LAST_NUMBER FROM DBA_SEQUENCES s WHERE s.SEQUENCE_OWNER = ''' || pinSequence_owner ||
                ''' AND s.SEQUENCE_NAME = ''' || pinSequence_name || '''';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strSQL INTO nNew_last_number;
  END IF;
END SET_SEQUENCE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Resetting sequence every month is not a valid approach. Basically you are violating the utilization of sequence. From your question i could understand, you wanted to append year and month to your column. In this case you can simple concatenate while inserting,

```
year||month||sequence_name.nextval

Eg: 2020||02||sequence_name.nextval
```

If you still wanted to reset, you can create a trigger to reset the sequence every month,

Comment: Reset it with a trigger?  And what event causes said trigger to fire?  No, it would be a scheduled job, not a trigger.

Comment: Trigger can be set up to execute with respect to Sysdate in Oracle. It does not require any scheduling process

Comment: could you point me to the documentation?  I'm not finding it in the 12.1 PL/SQL Language Reference.